# Disable Save Button When Row is Deleted in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

How can i able to disable the submit button if the row is deleted in reactive forms. I confused since i can do it with forms by  writing validators.required but how can i disable the submit button if the rows are deleted? Codes are below.

> html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreate()" >
  <div class="card-block" formArrayName="rows">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Material SKU</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of myForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <td>
            <select formControlName="material_id" class="col-md-10">
              <option *ngFor="let mat_order of mat_orders" [ngValue]="mat_order.material_id">
                {{ mat_order.sku}} - {{ mat_order.mat_name }} 
              </option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="quantity"></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="price"></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="col-md-6" formControlName="total"  [ngModel] ="row.get('quantity').value * row.get('price').value"></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-left" (click)="initGroup()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Add Row</button>
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

> ts

```
initGroup() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      material_id: [null, Validators.required],
      quantity: [null, Validators.required],
      price: [null, Validators.required],
      total: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
    }))
  }




this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      rows: this.fb.array([])
    })
```

Comment: you want to disable it when the table is empty ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID. Yes when the row is deleted on the table

Comment: to understand well your problem , if there is two rows in the table and the you delete one row ,the table now contains one row , will you disable the button in this case ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID. In that case. If there is one row left, button will be disabled if you didnt input data on that row. But what i meant is if there is no row on the table anymore, the button will be disabled too

Comment: see my answer  if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a solution to your problem you can set a `boolean` which will be `true` if you call the method `onDeleteRow(i)`  :

```
deleted : boolean = false;
onDeleteRow(i){
   this.deleted = true;
  //...
}
```

in the button you will check if `deleted` is `false` and if the rows are empty:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" [disabled]="!myForm.valid || myForm.controls.rows.length == 0 || deleted ">Save</button>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with this

```
[disabled]="!myForm.valid"
```

you can also put

```
[disabled]="!myForm.valid || myForm.pristine"
```

Comment: That doesn't work too. I can still click the submit button if the rows are empty

Answer (score 0):

After every value that get changed you check if your form is valid. If it's you set **saveButton** on true.
Add this code after you **created your form**:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((item: any) => {
       // item is changed
       if (this.form.valid) { this.saveButton = true; }
       else { this.saveButton = false; }
});
```

And in template **[disabled]="saveButton"**:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" [disabled]="saveButton">Save</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add ( in the html ) : 
`[disabled]="myForm.invalid"` to your Button

Edit :

I thought you would customize your conditions : I mean, 
You can put any condition you want in this, so you can add : `[disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.controls.rows.controls.length == 0"`

And you can even make a variable to exact behaviour you need : For example you can add to click event on click : 
`(click)="onDeleteRow(i); deletedRow = true;"` 
and then :
 `[disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.controls.rows.controls.length == 0 || deletedRow"`

Comment: You can put any condition you want in this, so you can add : 
[disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.controls.rows.controls.length == 0" 
And you can even make a variable to exact behaviour you need : For example you can add to click event on click :  (click)="onDeleteRow(i); deletedRow = true;" and then : [disabled]="myForm.invalid || myForm.controls.rows.controls.length == 0 || deletedRow"